# Decode result from ByteArray.readUTFBytes troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, actionscript-3

I create online flash game, and for transfer game result to game server i using RC4 cryptography.

```
var resultBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
resultBytes.writeUTFBytes(rawData);
rc4.encrypt(resultBytes);
resultBytes.position = 0;
var toServer:String = resultBytes.readUTFBytes(resultBytes.length);
```

On server side work C# ASP.Net service with same code

```
byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
```

and AS3 toServer string equivalent С# requestData, but AS3 resultBytes not equivalent C# resultBytes. And I can not decrypt request data.

I think troubles in different encoding rules on flash and C#, but how make it work correct?

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing the request data to the server, calling GetBytes will just give you a byte array of the string passed in, it's not clear what requestData contains.

Comment: To transfer data from flash i use typical URLLoader with URLVariables

On server i use WFC service. Like tihs
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public BattleVO EndBattle(int socialNetwork, string socialId, string authSig, string result, string sig)
{
....
}
where parametr result is encrypted data

Answer (score 0):

Despite all efforts, I did not understand differece beetwen AS3 ByteArray.readUTFBytes and C# Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData), and how to solve the problem.

As a result i write on client

```
var toServer:String = "";
for (var a:int = 0; a < resultBytes.length; a++) {
  toServer+= resultBytes[a].toString() + ",";           
}
```

and on server

```
string[] splited = requestData.Split(',');
byte[] resultBytes = new byte[splited.Length];

for (int a = 0; a < splited.Length; a++)
{
  if (splited[a] == String.Empty)
        continue;
  resultBytes[a] = byte.Parse(splited[a], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer);
}
```

This methos allow to get identical array of bytes on server for decryption.